# Текст в карусели накладывается друг на друга

Tags: html, css, slider

Проблема заключается в том, что есть slick slider, в котором 3 слайда. При выравнивании содержимого по центру, текст со всех трёх слайдов переносится на последний и накладывается друг на друга. Как можно решить проблему?

```css
.rigsCarousel {
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.rigsCarousel .slick-next {
  position: absolute;
  right: 30px;
  z-index: 10;
}

.rigsCarousel .slick-prev {
  position: absolute;
  left: 30px;
  z-index: 10;
}

.rigsCarousel .slick-dots {
  position: absolute;
  top: 270px;
}

.rigsCarousel img {
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
}

.rigsCarousel a {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  top: 200px;
}

.rigsCarousel h2 {
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  font-size: 52px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  top: 80px;
}

.rigsCarousel p {
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  top: 140px;
}
```

```html
<div class="rigsCarousel">
  <div class="rigsCarouselItem">
    <h2>Надпись 1</h2>
    <p>Описание первого слайда карусели</p>
    <a href="#">Читать дальше</a>
    <img src="{% static 'image\default_news_carousel.jpg' %}">
  </div>
  <div class="rigsCarouselItem">
    <h2>Надпись 2</h2>
    <p>Описание второго слайда карусели</p>
    <a href="#">Читать дальше</a>
    <img src="{% static 'image\default_news_carousel.jpg' %}">
  </div>
  <div class="rigsCarouselItem">
    <h2>Надпись 3</h2>
    <p>Описание третьего слайда карусели</p>
    <a href="#">Читать дальше</a>
    <img src="{% static 'image\default_news_carousel.jpg' %}">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вобщем очень долго бился с этой проблемой, в итоге решение довольно простое. HTML документ остался без изменений

```
.rigsCarousel {
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
}

.rigsCarousel img {
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
}

.rigsCarouselItem {
  position: relative;
}

.rigsCarousel .slick-next {
  position: absolute;
  right: 30px;
  z-index: 10;
}

.rigsCarousel .slick-prev {
  position: absolute;
  left: 30px;
  z-index: 10;
}

.rigsCarousel .slick-dots {
  position: absolute;
  top: 270px;
}

.rigsCarousel a {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  top: 200px;
}

.rigsCarousel h2 {
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  font-size: 52px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  top: 80px;
}

.rigsCarousel p {
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  top: 140px;
}
```